# OWIN FLOW (from MVC 5) to Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I've a website with 3 layers.....

1. MVC 5 (Presentation layer) with custom OWIN to store cookie. It checks with Service layer to validate user and then create a cookie.
2. Service layer (Class Library): Presentation layer has reference to this layer and any communication with database, needs to go through these.
3. Data layer (Class Library): Data layer with SQL statements. This layer is responsible for any communication with database. Service layer has reference to this.

All the above mentioned layers reside on same machine but within seperate projects. There is also potential that I've had to move all the layers to its own seperate servers (Presentation, Service, Data).

Now, once the user is authenticated and authorized, I want to basically pass the identity to Service and Data layers as I don't want anyone to call the service and data layers directly. But I don't know how to do it.

Could anyone please show me the light?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Cookie`/`Token` is only usable in browser-based environment (that means it only help to secure your `presentation` layer.

If you want to secure the `Presentation` layer (which is class library as you mentioned), quick and dirty way is **store a private key inside Web project, and every time you call a service, validate the private key passing in**.

Standard way is use **StrongNameIdentityPermission** to prevent others to reference your DLL. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermission.aspx)

Extra note: consider to use `obfuscator tool` to prevent others to decompile your DLL code.

Comment: is this the only way or there exists another Industry Standarized way to secure the Class library (acting as Service Layer and Data layer)?

Comment: @Johny: I updated my answer, standard way is to use StrongNameIdentityPermission to prevent others to reference my DLL. But this will require extra efforts to set up

Comment: Is there any online available example showing the "store a private key inside Web project, and every time you call a service, validate the private key passing in". I would avoid StrongNameIdentityPermission because sometimes my Service layer or Data Layer is directly referenced by my Batch processes. And some Services are available for public and most of them are not for Public. Moreover, apart from the 2 mentioned ways, is there any other way around?

Comment: @Johny: I cannot think of any other way for now. For the private key thing, just think about it as a normal parameter which will be passed in method signature. Depends on the project, you can store the key inside `web.config` or `database`

Comment: Thanks kienct89 for the help!